# Фон перекрывает картинку на сайте

Tags: html5, css3

[image: Так должны выглядеть в блоке картинки(на деле левая часть перекрывается чёрным фоном)]Здравствуйте! При вёрстке странички у меня возникла следующая проблема: в определенном участке фон перекрывает изображение. Третий день пытаюсь найти ошибку в коде, но не могу её найти. Вроде должно отображаться 2 картинки в одном блоке, но на деле отображается часть фона и вторая картинка. На скриншоте показан пример, как это должно выглядеть, на деле же у меня левая часть перекрывается чёрным фоном. Вот CSS код неработающей картинки: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WwQKpV

```
main .content2 .im2 {
    background-image: url("https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/meBaze-Freebies/512/setting.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
    min-height: 590px;
}
```

Comment: представьте себя на месте человека, отвечающего на вопрос. вы бы поняли что надо? что за картинка, что за фон. что за ОПРЕДЕЛЕННЫЙ УЧАСТОК?

Comment: ничо не понял, скриншоты сделайте, пожалуйста, тогда поможем, я думаю, что многие не поняли.

Comment: Добавил скриншот, надеюсь, будет понятнее

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну во первых: у Вас блок шириной в ноль, поставьте ширину ему нужную.
Во вторых: поставьте ему нужный z-index и будет Вам счастье.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло, даже не знаю, как я заметить этого не сумел)